# Month on month subscription users for a service. Calculating yearly growth

Tags: excel

I have a bunch of rows each having M1 TO M12, Month on month subscription users for a service. Need to find for each row the yearly growth rate. Have been using =M1/M12 ^(1/12)-1 formulae to get this. However if M1 is zero or if M12 is zero, this results in an error. Need in such cases the formulae to automatically pick up the first cell with a non zero value instead and also if the M12 value is zero, then to return 0% as the growth

Answer (score 0):

This is just one way to do it:

```
=IF(AND(M12<>0,M1<>0),M1/M12^(1/12)-1,"0%")
```

Note that I'm checking if the cells are not zero and assuming you have 'some' numeric value in the cell. In other words there are no other types of error check going on here.